# Convert Date to String - JAVA

Tags: java, string, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert current date into string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942857/how-to-convert-current-date-into-string-in-java)

I need to convert a DAte to String to user the method contains after
Can you help please !

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2942857/751090

Answer (score 1):

take a look at java.text.SimpleDateFormat

example:
  [How to convert current date into string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942857/how-to-convert-current-date-into-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You give little details about your situation, but it sounds like maybe you should use Calendar, rather than String.contains

[Calendar API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)