# Java: return date format in random date

Tags: java, date, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert current date into string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942857/how-to-convert-current-date-into-string-in-java)

How do I return the date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`? in

```
package random01;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class Random01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        Random random = new Random();
        String[] v = new String[5];

        for (int i = 0;
                i < v.length;
                i++) {
            //long tempo = (long) (1293861598 + random.nextDouble() * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
            Date dateFrom = dateFormat.parse("2012");
            long timestampFrom = dateFrom.getTime();
            Date dateTo = dateFormat.parse("2013");
            long timestampTo = dateTo.getTime();
            long timeRange = timestampTo - timestampFrom;
            long randomTimestamp = timestampFrom + (long) (random.nextDouble() * timeRange);
            System.out.println(randomTimestamp);
        }
    }
}
```

I need, example, 02/11/2012

Comment: See the Java Tutorial on this topic: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateintro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter.format(new Date(randomTimestamp)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for formatting as well as parsing:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
```