# convert a date as a string to a date as a string in another format

Tags: java, string, date, formatting

How can i parse String "2013-03-31", so i will get - "31 March 2013 Sun".
I tried to parse as bellow:

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy DD");
try {
    Date data = formatter.parse(eventDate);
    System.out.println(data);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

And i get `Unparseable date: "2013-03-31" (at offset 10)` exception text.

Is that String represented date is correct, and if correct how i must parse it.

Comment: Make sure the format that you are passing in to your `SimpleDateFormat` matches the format you are trying to parse.

Comment: How can i make sure it?

Comment: @Procurares. From [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Javadoc.

Comment: @Procurares : you really didn't need the Android tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input format: `"yyyy-MM-dd"`
Output format: `"dd MMMM yyyy EEE"`

```
final SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
final SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy EEE");
try {
    Date data = inputFormat.parse(eventDate);
    System.out.println(outputFormat.format(data));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: And how can i write output format "dd MMMM yyyy EEE" as 18 August 2013 Sunday?

Comment: Is your problem solved? To have the day of the week fully spelled out, try `EEEE` instead of `EEE`.

Answer (score 0):

see these links

string to date

[How to parse a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date)

[How to parse date string to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date)

date to string

[Convert java.util.Date to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string)

[How to convert current date into string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942857/how-to-convert-current-date-into-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a date input format:

```
String eventDate = "2013-03-31";

final SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
final SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd MMMM yyyy EEE");
try {

    Date date = inputFormat.parse(eventDate);
    System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getGmtTmFromLcl(String inputDtm, String inputFormat, String outputFormat) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);
        Date dt = format.parse(inputDtm);
        format = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat);
        return format.format(dt);
    }
```