# How can i get `String` date from calendar?

Tags: java, string, calendar

How can i get `String` date from calendar?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MOUNTH, -5); //set now and 5 days to back
```

I want get `String` like this(date on interval -5 days to TODAY):

```
11.03.2015
10.03.2015
.
.
.
07.03.2015
```

It's possible? How?

Comment: Take a look at SimpleDateFormat class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert current date into string in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942857/how-to-convert-current-date-into-string-in-java)

Comment: I want get all date, not only one.

Comment: Why do you say that it is a duplication , however, is something else entirely

Comment: I want get String date on interval -5 days to TODAY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use for loop and reduce one day from calendar instance and print it

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

for (int index = 1; index <= 5; index++) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

output:

```
10.03.2015
09.03.2015
08.03.2015
07.03.2015
06.03.2015
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `SimpleDateFormat` class, as follows.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MOUNTH -5);
SimpleDateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy"); //or ("dd.MM.yyyy"), If you want days before months.
String formattedDate = myDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: its only one, its possible get date between not time and -5?

Comment: Sorry @chefrisl, I understood your question only now. Prasad Khode's answer is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String strdate = sdf.format(calendardate.getTime());
```

Comment: I want get String date on interval -5 days to TODAY

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime();
Long beforeTime = date - (5*24*60*60*1000);
Date beforeDate = new Date(beforeTime);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String s = format.format(beforeDate);
```

s returns the date in your required format.

Comment: I want get String date on interval -5 days to TODAY

Comment: You can use the below logic in place of date in the above code snippet. (I modified it in the snippet above)

          Long beforeTime = (date.getTime())-(5*24*60*60*1000);
          Date beforeDate = new Date(beforeTime);