# How to separate month day year in saving into database

Tags: java

Hello I'm working on my system and I'm stuck right now on how to save separably the month day and year to a separate column .. In my system I have an objective that let user print report month or daily basis , and my solution is to save the day month and year to a each separate columns.. Is this posible ? Sorry for my bad english .

Comment: which Database? and whats table structure?

Comment: I use MySql , I have a table name Logs .. with column ID Name Date .. I want to make it ID NAME MONTH YEAR DAY . is it possible ?

Comment: @kaisarGreat Please edit your Question to provide detail and clarification rather than posting as a Comment. And no need to apologize for your English as we all know Stack Overflow is used around the world – and your English is quite good (better than the English of many Americans!).

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  However, this greatly depends on what your actual requirements mandate.  Are you saying that they need a different *type* to store based on month or day, or are you saying you absolutely need to represent a date as either a month, a day, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can take system date as String, as it can be seen from this resource: [How to convert current date into string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942857/how-to-convert-current-date-into-string-in-java)

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // Or ZoneOffset.UTC or ZoneId.systemDefault()
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId ) ;
String output = today.toString() ;
```

Later you can use split to divide string for needed values (Year, month of day), for example, like here: [How to split a String by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space)

```
str = "2017-05-03";
String[] splited = str.split("-");
```

In the last example instead "-", maybe, you need to use ASCII code of "-". Alas, I forget this

Comment: Sorry for late update , This approach works fine with me . thanks :D

Comment: Thanks, I am glad to be useful

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LocalDate from JDK 8 Date-Time API as below to get year, month and day and persist them in DB:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(); 
int year = date.getYear();
int month = date.getMonthValue(); // or Month month = date.getMonth() if you want month names
int day = date.getDayOfMonth();
```

Comment: Good answer, but I recommend always specifying the optional argument of your desired/expected time zone `ZoneId` in the call to `LocalDate.now` rather than relying implicitly on the JVM’a current default time zone that can change at any moment during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The other Answers are correct about using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) in Java.

## Database

As for the database, define your column as a date-only type such as the [SQL Standard‘s type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types) `DATE`.

## JDBC

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complies with [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), you can use the java.time types such as [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) directly.

```
myPreparedStmt.setObject( … , myLocalDate ) ;
```

And:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

If your driver does not comply, fall back to using the [java.sql](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) types. You may convert to-and-fro by calling new methods added to the old classes. But use the java.sql types as briefly as possible, doing all the real work with java.time classes.

```
myPreparedStmt.setDate( … , java.sql.Date.valueOf( myLocalDate ) ) ;
```

…and…

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getDate( … ).toLocalDate() ;
```